# Find $\lim f(x)$ without a formula for $f(x)$ but given a constraint

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

**Introduction**.  I memorized the problem and I could be getting the constant term wrong in the numerator inside the absolute value, but I feel it won't matter.  For instance, I don't think we would have cancelled anything there.  My concern is that I don't know how to verify my answer here in any interesting way.  How would I verify this?

**Problem**.  Suppose

$$\left|f(x)- \frac{7x^2 + 5x|x| + 2}{x^2 + 16}\right| \leq \frac{1}{x^2}$$

Find $\lim f(x)$ as $x\to \pm\infty$.

**A solution**.  I'll show my approach for $x\to -\infty$.  I open the absolute value and rewrite the polynomial to $7x^2 - 5x^2 + 2$ because $|x| = x$ and $x < 0$ when $x \to -\infty$.  I then added the rational function from both inequalities and then divided every term in the rational function by $x^2$.  I got

$$-\frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{2 + 2/x^2}{1 + 16/x^2} \leq f(x) \leq \frac{2 + 2/x^2}{1 + 16/x^2} + \frac{1}{x^2}$$

Letting $x\to -\infty$, the left term goes to $2$ and the right term goes to $2$ too, so $f(x) \to 2$ as $x\to -\infty$.

**Question**.  How do I verify the approach here?  I don't even know how to ask a CAS to verify this.

Comment: Your approach is fine -- and  f(x) approaches 12 as x approaches +infinity.

Comment: Thank you for the verification!  Very appreciated.